# A function to create a new column based on existing one in a dataframe using ifelse()

Tags: r, function, if-statement

Hey i have a simple function called cont_to_cat that i can not get to work. Basically what i want this function to do is create another column in the dataframe df based on a column called here score_col (the parameter of the function is a string) in the same dataframe df. I want to create this new column(i want to call it 'cat-'+score_col) based on conditions on the other column (first condition if df$score_col<6 new column equals "Rating: 6-" ..)

```
#dataframe to test
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=0, max=10), nrow=10))
cont_to_cat<-function(df,score_col){
  s<-paste('cat_',score_col,sep='')
  print(s)
  print(df[[score_col]])
  df$s <- with(df, ifelse(df$score_col <6,'Rating: 6-',
                          ifelse(df$score_col >=6 & df$score_col < 7, 'Good: 6+',
                                 ifelse(df$score_col >=7 & df$score_col < 8, 'Very good: 7+',
                                        ifelse(df$score_col >=8 & df$score_col < 9, 'Fabulous: 8+',
                                               ifelse(df$score_col >= 9, 'Superb: 9+','NULL'))))))
  return(df)
}
new_df<-cont_to_cat(df,'V1')
```

after i run this code i get the error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w7GC.png)
(Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "s", value = logical(0)) :
le tableau de remplacement a 0 lignes, le tableau remplacé en a 10)
This bug got me inactive for a while. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be missing a trick to not take advantage of `cut` to do this in one go without having to write out the start and end of each range manually:

```
cont_to_cat <- function(data, score_col) {
    s <- paste0('cat_', score_col)
    data[s] <- cut(
        data[[score_col]],
        breaks=c(0,6,7,8,9,Inf),
        labels=c("Rating: 6-", "Good: 6+", "Very Good: 7+", "Fabulous: 8+", "Superb: 9+")
    )
    data
}
```

Using @Jilber's example data:

```
cont_to_cat(df, score_col="V1")
#         V1     cat_V1
#1  9.209413 Superb: 9+
#2  2.704474 Rating: 6-
#3  5.798527 Rating: 6-
#4  9.527739 Superb: 9+
#5  3.151152 Rating: 6-
#6  2.834159 Rating: 6-
#7  2.198065 Rating: 6-
#8  3.471788 Rating: 6-
#9  4.057178 Rating: 6-
#10 6.823411   Good: 6+
```

You could even add the breaks and labels as parameters to the function so that it is even more flexible and can be reused for other categorisations:

```
cont_to_cat2 <- function(data, score_col, breaks, labels) {
    s <- paste0('cat_', score_col)
    data[s] <- cut(data[[score_col]], breaks=breaks, labels=labels)
    data
}

cont_to_cat2(
    df, score_col="V1", breaks=c(0,6,7,8,9,Inf),
    labels=c("Rating: 6-", "Good: 6+", "Very Good: 7+", "Fabulous: 8+", "Superb: 9+")
)
```

Comment: ah thank u. i know what s the problem with my data it has NA that s why it doesnt work on my dataset. Do u know how i can handle this?

Comment: @AbdelkabirMENANI - `NA`s shouldn't be a problem with this function. `cut` will return `NA` for any value in `score_col` that is `NA`, which in my opinion would be the correct output.

Comment: but i have this error while i tried the function on my dataset :( can u help me debug it:

error in `[.data.table`(x, i, which = TRUE) : 
When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: @AbdelkabirMENANI - you have a *data.table* not a *data.frame* - either pass `data=as.data.frame(df)` to the function or rejig the assignment part in the function to work with data.table - `data[, (s) := cut(data[[score_col]], breaks=breaks, labels=labels)]; data[]`

Comment: Wow thanks man. I really appreciate it. I am new to R i didnt even know a structure called data.table in R till now. Thanks.

Comment: hey do you know how to change missing values of a data table column to a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case_when` to avoid nested `ifelse`

```
> set.seed(15151)
> df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=0, max=10), nrow=10))
> cont_to_cat <- function(df, score_col){  

  output <-  mutate(df, score = case_when(score_col < 6 ~ "Rating: 6-",
                             score_col >= 6 & score_col < 7  ~ "Good:6+",
                             score_col >= 7  & score_col < 8 ~ "Very good: 7+",
                             score_col >= 8 & score_col < 9 ~ "Fabulous: 8+",
                             score_col >= 9 ~ "Superb: 9+"))
  
  names(output)[names(output) == "score"] <- paste0("cat_", score_col)

  return(output)
  
}
> cont_to_cat(df, score_col = "V1")

         V1   cat_V1
1  9.209413 Superb: 9+
2  2.704474 Rating: 6-
3  5.798527 Rating: 6-
4  9.527739 Superb: 9+
5  3.151152 Rating: 6-
6  2.834159 Rating: 6-
7  2.198065 Rating: 6-
8  3.471788 Rating: 6-
9  4.057178 Rating: 6-
10 6.823411    Good:6+
```

Comment: that works but can you do it as a function.. because my code works outside a function but when i would like to automate it so i can do it on various columns at the same time it doesnt work. The function i want is like this function(df,score_col) it takes the dataframe and the score_col(string) and i want the new column to be named "cat_"+score_col as explained in the question: that is why i added this command:            s<-paste('cat_',score_col,sep='')

Comment: but that isnt exactly what i want to do.. i want to give the function a name of a column (score_col here) "review" for example and i want the new column that will be created by the function called "cat_review". Another example if the column is called "staff" i want the column created by the function called "cat_staff". Other than that the code works good